# Jersey multiple constructor @inject

Tags: java, jersey

I am creating two constructor for my jersey resource, however only one is the one being able to call,

here is the sample code,

```
public class jerseyresoure {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @Inject 
    public jerseyresoure (String name){
          this.name = name;
    }

    @Inject 
    public jerseyresoure (int age){
          this.age= age;
    }
}
```

the get cosntructor with the parameter int is the one being called successfully,
can you help me with this scenario?

Comment: how do you call it? Why is `@inject` lowercase?

Comment: sorry my bad, the @Inject should be capital I,

Comment: so which one works? Try with `Integer` instead of `int`, however I would expect autoboxing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CDI specification it is illegal to annotate more than one constructor with `@Inject` (see section 3.9 of the CDI specification):

> If a bean class does not explicitly declare a constructor using @Inject, the constructor that accepts no parameters is the bean
>   constructor.
>
> If a bean class has more than one constructor annotated @Inject, the container automatically detects the problem and treats it
>   as a definition error.
>
> A bean constructor may have any number of parameters. All parameters of a bean constructor are injection points.

So what you can do is as follows:

```
public class jerseyresoure {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @Inject 
    public jerseyresoure (String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

I assume you are using a producer method so that values (*name* and *age*) get injected.